# Finding the location of a max int in a list

Tags: python, list, location

If given a simple example:

```
k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l = [20, 50, 1, 100]
```

How can I write in one line, the simplest code to get the item in list k that corresponds with the location of the highest number of list l?

```
k[max(l)]
```

totally no idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first occurrence of the highest number can be found like -

```
ans = k[l.index(max(l))]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(zip(k, l),key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Or using python 2:

```
  from itertools import izip

  max(izip(k, l),key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

If `l` happens to be longer using zip you will get the max up to the corresponding lengths.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> l = [20, 50, 1, 100]
>>> k[l.index(max(l))]
'd'
```